# entity framework и WinFoms не работает сохранение

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, entity-framework

уже долгое время мучаюсь с сохранением в базу данных.
Есть проект на WinForms, подключил к нему локальную БД и entity framework, создал модель по базе (одна таблица), пробую сохранить и ничего не выходит, так же не выводит ни какую ошибку.

```
            using (DatabaseTestTaskEntities db = new DatabaseTestTaskEntities())
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = db.TableMainTask.ToList();
            TableMainTask c = new TableMainTask { id = 4, indexid = "gggg" };
            db.TableMainTask.Add(c);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: А данные он выгружает в GridView?

Comment: Да выгружает в этом и странность.

Comment: Он как бы записывает пока программа запущена, но после перезапуска в бд не сохраняется ничего.

Comment: дайте угадаю, у вас БД - это файлик в проекте и в него не добавляются данные, когда в добавляете данные в дебаге, и при этом ошибок нет, да?

Comment: Вы когда компилируете программу и запускаете, она запускается из папки `ваш проект\bin\debug` - там она и создает копию БД, с которой работает. А вы проверяете данные (точнее, что их нет) в файле, который лежит где то рядом с исходниками (наверное прямо в папке проекта). Зайдите в ваш `bin\debug` каталог и ищите БД там

Comment: tym32167, спасибо вам попали в точку, в App.config путь к БД был через |DataDirectory|, поменял на свой и все стало работать как надо)

Comment: Может еще кто подсказать как записать огромный массив данных в БД с наименьшими затратами системы?

Comment: Оформил ответом. Если у вас есть второй вопрос - задавайте его отдельным вторым вопросом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы когда компилируете программу и запускаете, она запускается из папки `ваш проект\bin\debug` - там она и создает копию БД, с которой работает. А вы проверяете данные (точнее, что их нет) в файле, который лежит где то рядом с исходниками (наверное прямо в папке проекта). Зайдите в ваш `bin\debug` каталог и ищите БД там.