# После изменения объявление строки подключения перестали сохранятся любые изменения в БД

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.
В своей программе я использовал следующее объявление строки подключения:

```
public static string conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Dmitriy\\Desktop\\myproject\\myproject\\myprojectDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
```

При установке и запуске программы на другом компьютере я получал ошибку подключения к базе. Я решил, что проблема со строкой подключения, так как путь к базе на другом компьютере будет отличаться.

Поэтому я изменил объявление строки подключения во всех формах следующим образом:

```
public static string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.myprojectDBConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
```

Строка подключения теперь приняла следующий вид:

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="|DataDirectory|\myprojectDB.mdf";Integrated Security=True"
```

И теперь любые изменения, внесенные в базу данных попросту не сохраняются после закрытия приложения.
Как мне правильно задать строку подключения, чтобы она распознавалась на других ПК и не было проблемы с сохранием данных, которая возникла у меня?
Я не очень давно начал изучать c#, поэтому заранее извините за ляпы.
Может ли кто-нибудь помочь с этим?

Comment: запустите вашу програму напрямую из папки `bin\debug`, мнесите изменения и перезапустите программу из той же папки. Изменения сохранятся?

Comment: @tym32167 да, если запускать из папки debug, то все сохраняется.

Comment: ну то есть у вас есть БД в вашем проекте, которая при каждой компиляции копируется в `bin\debug`. Когда вы запускаете программу через студию, то происходит копирование БД. После вы вносите свои изменения в эту копию, изменения в копии сохраняются. Но при перезапуске программы через студию вы ваша БД перетирается базой из проекта и все ваши изменения пропадают.

Comment: ваша проблема похожа на [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864664/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за ссылку, до меня уже и так дошло)
Мне кажется, хорошим решением будет закинуть файл базы данных в созданную мной папку в Моих документах, к примеру ( и указать в строке подключения этот путь), и при установке программы на другом компьютере устанавливать файлы базы данных тоже в Мои документы в папку с таким же именем, верно?

Comment: я так не думаю. Хорошее решение - не зависеть от данных в БД во время разработки. Например, [в моем проекте](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient), у меня нет БД в файлах проекта, БД просто сама создастся если её нет в `debug\output` со всеми нужными мне таблицами.