# Записи добавляются в приложении winforms, но LocalDB не обновляется

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio

есть приложение по работе с локальной базой данных, то есть добавление записей, обновление и т.д. Сам SQL connection  прописан не к расположению MDF, так как в последующем приложение должно работать по локальной сети, по другому незнаю как реализовать, в свойствах dataset указано "копировать в более позднюю версию". Проблема состоит в том что после изменения базы через  приложение в таблицах и дальнейшей работе отображаются все изменения, даже после повторного запуска ещё на протяжении какого то времени изменения остаются. Но через пару минут все исчезает, а в таблице данных в visual studio не отображается никаких изменений. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Коннектитесь к файлику БД куда? в тот же каталог, где exe файлик лежит? Бывает ошибка у новичка такая, ведь на каждый билд студия может все в папке bin\debug удалить и заново туда скопировать базу, в которой изменений нет.

Comment: Строка подключения выглядит так:  <<string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";>>, не указываю путь к каталогу, потому что боюсь проблем с коннектом после переноса приложения на другие устройства.  
А в свойствах dataset почему то указан путь к начальному каталогу, а не bin с exeшником и я не могу его поменять :")

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864664/179763 ?

Comment: Да, изменила путь к бд, все получилось, спасибо